# NodeJS Passport: Possible to authenticate roles?

Tags: node.js

I have `node.js` and passport working, using `passport.js` docs.

My question is, can I authenticate differently, using a `LocalStrategy` for different roles?

I have regular users, and admin users, and of course, some pages are only for admins.

Answer (score 4):

I was five minutes away from answering my own question.

You can find User entity data in req.user with passport.

so I can use this

```
if (req.user.role == "Admin") {
  // render page here
} else {
  // redirect somewhere else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your have to design your database in a manner where you can remember if user is a admin or regular users etc (i.e you will have to make the data persist).

Now as to how to use this local strategy? I really doubt you need that in local strategy unless you are looking for your user to login every time he requests a new page with his username and password. You should be using sessions, you could add a special special req.role in user de-serialize method.

Now for every view you need to check whether the user's role allow him to view it or not? You can define a custom strategy that checks this for you? In that strategy just check for req.user.role and allow for a particular role per page.

I hope this helps you!!!